# What is the use of female to female SATA cable with power?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, sata

The other day I accidentally bought a female to female SATA cable with power cable next to it.
[image: female to female SATA with power]
Since the power and SATA itself is right next to each other and there is no way to separate them unless I cut them in half, I currently have no use for it.
Does anyone have good idea what this is used for?

Comment: There is usb2sata adapters that has pretty limited cable length, I think such cables might be used as extender cable. Hook one end to SATA drive and another end to usb2sata adaptter

Comment: Actually its purpose is being an extender, period. To extend to something that otherwise would be out of range, any SATA adapter or controller.

Comment: I suppose USB to SATA extender is male to female.
Also for sockets like ones on laptops which hard drives directly stick into, we can only use male to female extender.
Is there any case where female to female connectors come in handy?